# What has happened to totten/lurkerlite?

Tags: installation, composer

Problem 1
Installing CiviCRM using Composer has started giving these errors:

```
    - Root composer.json requires civicrm/composer-compile-plugin ^0.14.0 -> satisfiable by civicrm/composer-compile-plugin[v0.14].
    - civicrm/composer-compile-plugin v0.14 requires totten/lurkerlite ^1.3 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Problem 2

```
    - civicrm/composer-compile-plugin v0.14 requires totten/lurkerlite ^1.3 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
    - civicrm/civicrm-core 5.31.1 requires civicrm/composer-compile-lib ~0.3 || ~1.0 -> satisfiable by civicrm/composer-compile-lib[v0.3, v0.4].
    - civicrm/composer-compile-lib[v0.3, ..., v0.4] require civicrm/composer-compile-plugin ~0.9 || ~1.0 -> satisfiable by civicrm/composer-compile-plugin[v0.14].
```

Does anyone know what has gone wrong?

Comment: That error is also output as a "default" error when composer doesn't know what the problem is. Maybe try running with -v and see if it gives more info?

Comment: I tried, and it didn't show anything more.  I am deleting the whole directory tree and restoring from backup to see if I get any further..  I am beginning to conclude that the Composer environment is too fragile for a production system - it breaks too easily.  Fortunately, I am not working on such a system at the moment.   It may just be that I am ignorant about certain aspects of Composer.

Comment: Yeah. Composer is definitely not at the top of my list of tools. It's like a phillips screwdriver - it works sometimes but mostly it just strips the screws and makes them unusable. The other screwdrivers are better.

Comment: Yeah, for a production system, it's good to have some additional change-tracking (like periodic tarballs or site-repo). Tangentially, I've also raised composer-upgrade-reliability in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/142

Answer (score 1):

```
- civicrm/composer-compile-plugin v0.14 requires totten/lurkerlite ^1.3
   -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

The error message suggests a typo, which I think is misleading/incorrect. Let me give some counter-indicators -- and then some alternative theories.

The name and version should be correct because:

- (A1) In the official directory of composer packages (`packagist.org`), it lists `totten/lurkerlite` with version 1.3.0 as available. See: https://packagist.org/packages/totten/lurkerlite
- (A2) If I create a new project with a minimalist `composer.json`, then it does manage to install `totten/lurkerlite`.

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/abcd
  cd /tmp/abcd
  echo '{}' > composer.json
  composer config minimum-stability dev
  composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages}:5.31.1
  ls vendor/totten/lurkerlite/
  ```

You may want to try a new/empty project like this yourself. If the new/empty project works, then that points to an issue in the local `composer.{json,lock}` (like B1/B2/B4). If the new/empty project also fails, then that points to an issue in the upstream or tooling (like B3/B4).

Some alternative theories:

- (B1) `composer.lock` may become overly opinionated. Try clearing it even more aggressively:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/old-stuff
  mv composer.lock vendor /tmp/old-stuff
  composer install
  ```
- (B2) `composer.json` may become overly opinionated or have old/redundant constraints. Double-check the current list of [recommended packages](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/) and then read your local `composer.json`. See if there are any extra/redundant constraints.
- (B3) `composer` has a local cache (e.g. `~/.cache/composer/`). This cache could be corrupted/stale (e.g. if there was a network-error or disk-error at the wrong moment).  Try clearing it out.
- (B4) `composer` can be configured with alternative repositories/feeds. If the configuration disables or supercedes  `packagist.org`, then it might not get a consistent feed. (*Most people don't disable packagist -- if you do this, then you should know about it.*)

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  I was running Composer under Windows from PowerShell.  Running under Git Bash seems to work better, but I'll bear those suggestions in mind if the problem recurs.